# How do I time a program executing in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, timing

I want to be able to do the Windows equivalent of this Unix/Linux command:

time foo`enter code here`

```
foo
x cpu time
y real time
z wallclock time
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timeit` from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&DisplayLang=en) should do the trick.